# Will article-style citations in a presentation be indexed by Google Scholar?

Tags: presentation

If a presentation is made public and can be found by Google Scholar, will it read through it and add to the citations if a paper was under a nicely written "References" section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list on the [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) website regarding the requirements for when a paper is indexed:

> a. the full text of your paper is in a PDF file that ends with ".pdf",
> b. the title of the paper appears in a large font on top of the first page,
> c. the authors of the paper are listed right below the title on a separate line,
> d. and there's a bibliography section titled, e.g., "References" or "Bibliography" at the end.

So from this we can infer that the crawler looks for a section titled 'references' or 'bibliography' in a document. Assuming that the rest of the requirements are fulfilled, it might work.

However, it is hard to say for certain whether the crawler will actually pick this up since the exact workings of Google Scholar are fairly opaque.